# What do the "Allan_Dwan__1", "Abraham_Lincoln__1" (entities_numericals) like entries mean in instance_types dataset of DBpedia?

Tags: rdf, dbpedia

In the instance_types_en dataset of DBpedia (below is a partial extract of the dataset), what do the entries like `Allan_Dwan__1`, `Allan_Dwan__2`, `Abraham_Lincoln__1` (similar entities) etc. mean?

I do not understand the type `PersonFunction`, `TimePeriod`. Can somebody explain?

```
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Allan_Dwan> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Person> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Allan_Dwan__1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PersonFunction> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Allan_Dwan__2> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PersonFunction> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Allan_Dwan__3> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/PersonFunction> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abraham_Lincoln> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/OfficeHolder> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abraham_Lincoln__1> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/TimePeriod> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abraham_Lincoln__2> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/TimePeriod> .
<http://dbpedia.org/resource/Abraham_Lincoln__3> <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/TimePeriod> .
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are used to represent relationships that are potentially more complicated than what can be represented by a single triplet. For example, for `dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1`, [the whole set of triplets it's in](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select+%3Fs+%3Fp+%3Fo%0D%0Awhere+%7B%0D%0A%7B%0D%0Adbr%3AAbraham_Lincoln__1+%3Fp+%3Fo.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0AUNION%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%3Fs+%3Fp+dbr%3AAbraham_Lincoln__1.%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&CXML_redir_for_subjs=121&CXML_redir_for_hrefs=&timeout=30000&debug=on) is:

```
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln dbo:termPeriod dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 dbo:office "President of the United States"
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 dbo:activeYearsStartDate 1861-03-04
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 dbo:activeYearsEndDate 1865-04-15
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 rdf:type dbo:TimePeriod
dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 rdf:type owl:Thing
```

Comment: So is dbr:Abraham_Lincoln__1 here a blank node?

Comment: No it's a URI for a period of time. In this case Lincolns presidency.

Comment: @Gita I think it serves the same purpose as blank node, but it's not technically a blank node.